# Block FTP access from folder

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Let's say I have an FTP user that I have given access to public_html, but I don't want them to have access to a certain folder within public_html.  Is there a way to block their access from this certain folder, but let them have access to everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the owner and group of the sub folder, then chmod the "other" permissions to 0

EDIT:

To answer your comment. Say I have user A who you want to have access to folder A but not Folder B under it

```
 drwxr-xr--    UserA UserA FolderA
```

Under folderA is folder B

```
 drwxr-xr-x    UserA UserA FolderB
```

So drwxr-xr-x is read as "It's a directory" The owner (UserA) has RWX the group (UserA) has RX and everyone else (other) has RX

The last part tells you that if the person is not UserA and not in the UserA group they still have R to the folder.

If you changed the permissions to look like this:

```
 drwxr-wr--     UserA UserA FolderA
```

User A still has everything they need for accessing that folder.

```
 drwxr-x---     UserB UserB FolderB
```

Now User A cannot access FolderB. you would accomplish this by :

```
 chown UserB:UserB FolderB
 chmod 750 FolderB
```

The 750 Says Owner has RWX, Group has RX and Everyone else (other) has no rights to this folder.

Comment: The owner and group are already set to the main ftp user.  What do you mean by chmod the "other" permissions.

Comment: Please see my edit. better formatting